# Is more than one free variable necessary for the axiom schemas in Peano arithmetic and ZFC set theory?

Tags: logic

The axiom schema of induction in Peano Arithmetic that I read about in Wikipedia concerns a tuple of free variables $(x, y_1,..., y_k)$. My question is whether more than $x$ is necessary. In other words, would the theory be strictly weaker if we only allowed one free variable in the axiom schema of induction. A similar question can be asked in the axiom schemas of comprehension and replacement in ZFC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can indeed drop parameters from the induction scheme in PA; see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/79174/parameters-in-arithmetic-induction-axiom-schemas).

The situation is the same for ZFC; see [this paper of Schindler and Schlicht](http://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/schlicht/ZFC_without_parameters.pdf).

---

However, both of these facts are nontrivial, and in general parameter-free systems tend to be much weaker than their fully-parameterized counterparts. So I'd personally argue that even though we *can* omit parameters in the presentations, we *shouldn't*.