# What does the parameter $p$ refer to in this context?

Tags: logic, set-theory, propositional-calculus, axioms

I'm reading about the axioms of set theory (from Jech), and I'm having some confusion. There are various parts where it talks about well-formed formulas that include a parameter $p$.

This appears here:

[image]

Also here:

[image]

Why do we need to include $p$? Couldn't I have just written $\varphi(x, y)$ instead of $\varphi(x, y, p)$?

What kind of parameter is it anyways? Is it a natural number that you plug in? These are very basic questions, but I genuinely don't understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it may help to see a specific (if rather boring) application. For example, suppose we want to show the following:

> $(*)\quad$ For every $p$ and every set $A$, the class $$\{\{a, p\}: a\in A\}$$ is a set.

This is a variant of the argument that for every set $A$ the class $\{\{a\}: a\in A\}$ is a set.

The $p$ above enters the Replacement scheme as a parameter: the result $(*)$ follows from the instance of replacement corresponding to the three-variable formula $$\varphi(x,y,z)\equiv y=\{x,z\}$$ (or a bit more precisely, "$\forall u(u\in y\leftrightarrow u=x\vee u=z)$"), since this instance says exactly "For all $A$ and all $p$ the class of $y$ such that for some $x\in A$ we have $\varphi(x,y,p)$ is a set."

*Now it turns out that we ultimately don't need to include parameters in our axioms after all - see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441622/is-more-than-one-free-variable-necessary-for-the-axiom-schemas-in-peano-arithmet). But this is a very nontrivial and context-specific result; "morally speaking," it is important to include parameters in the Separation and Replacement axioms.*

Comment: Sorry for such a late response, but I have one remaining question. Why can't I include the $p$ variable as part of the well-formed formula, so instead of writing $\varphi(x, y, p)$ I'd write $\varphi_{p}(x, y)$ where $\varphi_{p}$ is the formula that includes $p$.

Comment: @MaximalIdeal What does that even mean? What would $\varphi_p$ actually look like?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I had a closely related question here :  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4831130/522332. Perhaps you could enlighten me?